# SQL Algorithm For Two JOINs On One Table Based On If Condition

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, select, join

How could be correctly written syntax of this query? -

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_first`
LEFT JOIN `table_second` ON table_second.type_id1 = table_first.type_id1
```

Until here everything is fine. Now comes the problematic part:

```
LEFT JOIN `table_third` ON 
IF (table_first.id>10) 
BEGIN table_third.id= table_first.type_id2 END 
ELSE 
BEGIN table_third.id = table_second.type_id2 END)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use CASE-WHEN-ELSE-END:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_first`
LEFT JOIN `table_second` ON table_second.type_id1 = table_first.type_id1
LEFT JOIN `table_third` ON table_third.id = CASE WHEN table_first.id > 10 THEN table_first.type_id2 ELSE table_second.type_id2 END;
```

Depending on a condition in each WHEN it returns a corresponding expression in THEN.

Answer (score 1):

What's problematic?

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_first` LEFT JOIN
     `table_second`
     ON table_second.type_id1 = table_first.type_id1 LEFT JOIN
     `table_third`
     ON ((table_first.id > 10) and (table_third.id = table_first.type_id2)) or
        ((table_first.id <= 10) and (table_third.id = table_second.type_id2))
```

When there is no matches for the last condition, you will get `NULL`s in the corresponding columns for `table_third`.

EDIT:

Often for performance reasons, you would want to do this as two separate joins, and then use `coalesce()` in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT . . ., coalesce(t3a.col1, t3b.col1) as col1, . . .
FROM `table_first` LEFT JOIN
     `table_second`
     ON table_second.type_id1 = table_first.type_id1 LEFT JOIN
     `table_third` t3a
     ON (table_first.id > 10) and (t3a.id = table_first.type_id2) LEFT JOIN
     table_third t3b or
     ON (table_first.id <= 10) and (t3b.id = table_second.type_id2)
```

This makes it easier for the database optimizer to use indexes for the query.

Comment: This solutions also is correct, but this time it is more efficient for me to use Multisync user answer. Thanks!